# Show only users with the same role in Dashboard user list

Tags: users, user-roles, wp-user-query

I'm trying to see in the dashboard user list only the users with the same role of the logged in user.

For example, i have Admin, Mod and Subscribers roles, when I'm a Subscriber i want to show only the Subscribers role users in the dashboard user list and hide the other users and roles.

Can i do something like this?
Thanks
Alex

Comment: have you tried the `pre_get_users` filter?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want your admins to not be able to see subscribers?